# Array of objects, group by object key:value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects like this:

```
const data = [
      { id: 1, type: { name: "A" }, condition: "new" },
      { id: 2, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "broken" },
      { id: 3, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "brand new" },
      { id: 4, type: { name: "B" }, condition: "broken" },
      { id: 5, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "brand new" },
      { id: 6, type: { name: "A" }, condition: "new" },
      { id: 7, type: { name: "A" }, condition: "new" },
      { id: 8, type: { name: "B" }, condition: "broken" },
      { id: 9, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "broken" }
    ];
```

What i'm trying to do is to group those objects by type's `key:value` in this case by `name:value`, like this:

```
const data = [
      {
        by: {
          type: { name: "A" }
        },
        chunks: [
          { id: 1, type: { name: "A" }, condition: "new" },
          { id: 6, type: { name: "A" }, condition: "new" },
          { id: 7, type: { name: "A" }, condition: "new" }
        ]
      },
      {
        by: {
          type: { name: "C" }
        },
        chunks: [
          { id: 2, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "broken" },
          { id: 3, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "brand new" },
          { id: 5, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "brand new" },
          { id: 9, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "broken" }
        ]
      },
      {
        by: {
          type: { name: "B" }
        },
        chunks: [
          { id: 4, type: { name: "B" }, condition: "broken" },
          { id: 8, type: { name: "B" }, condition: "broken" }
        ]
      },
    ];
```

I've tried to use lodash and `Array.prototype.reduce()` , my last attempt was using lodash, but i can't get the type as object.

```
_.chain(channels)
      .groupBy("type.name")
      .map((item, i) => {
        return {
          chunks: item,
          by: i
        };
      })
      .value();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Map` to collect the data by group, and then its `values()` method will iterate the data as you want:

```js
const data = [{ id: 1, type: { name: "A" }, condition: "new" },{ id: 2, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "broken" },{ id: 3, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "brand new" },{ id: 4, type: { name: "B" }, condition: "broken" },{ id: 5, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "brand new" },{ id: 6, type: { name: "A" }, condition: "new" },{ id: 7, type: { name: "A" }, condition: "new" },{ id: 8, type: { name: "B" }, condition: "broken" },{ id: 9, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "broken" }];

const map = new Map(data.map(o => [o.type.name, { by: { type: o.type.name }, chunks: [] }]));
data.forEach(o => map.get(o.type.name).chunks.push(o));
const result = [...map.values()];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```js
const data = [
      { id: 1, type: { name: "A" }, condition: "new" },
      { id: 2, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "broken" },
      { id: 3, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "brand new" },
      { id: 4, type: { name: "B" }, condition: "broken" },
      { id: 5, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "brand new" },
      { id: 6, type: { name: "A" }, condition: "new" },
      { id: 7, type: { name: "A" }, condition: "new" },
      { id: 8, type: { name: "B" }, condition: "broken" },
      { id: 9, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "broken" }
];

let names = [];
data.forEach(x => {
  if (names.indexOf(x.type.name)==-1) {
    names.push(x.type.name);
  }
});

let grouped = names.map(name => ({
  by: { type: {name}},
  chunks: data.filter(x => x.type.name==name)
}));
console.log(grouped);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't group by an object because two objects with the same keys and values are not the same object, you can use `JSON.stringify()` to convert the object to a string, and group by it. Use `Array.reduce()` to group the items by the stringified object. Convert to pairs using `Object.entries()`, then map the values to an object, and extract the `by` value using `JSON.parse()`:

```js
const groupByObj = (arr, key) => Object.entries(
  arr.reduce((r, o) => {
    const k = JSON.stringify({ [key]: o[key] });
    
    r[k] = r[k] || [];
    
    r[k].push(o);
    
    return r;
  }, {})
).map(([k, chunks]) => ({
  by: JSON.parse(k),
  chunks
}));

const data = [{"id":1,"type":{"name":"A"},"condition":"new"},{"id":2,"type":{"name":"C"},"condition":"broken"},{"id":3,"type":{"name":"C"},"condition":"brand new"},{"id":4,"type":{"name":"B"},"condition":"broken"},{"id":5,"type":{"name":"C"},"condition":"brand new"},{"id":6,"type":{"name":"A"},"condition":"new"},{"id":7,"type":{"name":"A"},"condition":"new"},{"id":8,"type":{"name":"B"},"condition":"broken"},{"id":9,"type":{"name":"C"},"condition":"broken"}];

const result = groupByObj(data, 'type');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce` and `Object.values` to group like this:

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"type":{"name":"A"},"condition":"new"},{"id":2,"type":{"name":"C"},"condition":"broken"},{"id":3,"type":{"name":"C"},"condition":"brand new"},{"id":4,"type":{"name":"B"},"condition":"broken"},{"id":5,"type":{"name":"C"},"condition":"brand new"},{"id":6,"type":{"name":"A"},"condition":"new"},{"id":7,"type":{"name":"A"},"condition":"new"},{"id":8,"type":{"name":"B"},"condition":"broken"},{"id":9,"type":{"name":"C"},"condition":"broken"}];
    
const merged = data.reduce((acc, o) => {
  const {type} = o;
  acc[type.name] =  acc[type.name] || { by: { type }, chunks:[] };
  acc[type.name].chunks.push(o)
  return acc;
},{})
    
const output = Object.values(merged)
console.log(output)
```

(Ignore snippet `console` and check browser's console)

Comment: Your answer was the most beautiful and simplest to read. Also it helps to solve my problem and you did not use other for-loops or conditions which is great. But it will not be compatible in IE. Thanks

Comment: @DorinMusteața I think all answers posted here use some ES6 features which doesn't work on IE :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Here the idea is

- Use `name` as key and checks if `op` already has that particular key or not. if the key is already there we push the `inp` to `chunks` property of op. if not we add a new key with `by` and `chunks` with respective values.

```js
const data = [{ id: 1, type: { name: "A" }, condition: "new" },{ id: 2, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "broken" },{ id: 3, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "brand new" },{ id: 4, type: { name: "B" }, condition: "broken" },{ id: 5, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "brand new" },{ id: 6, type: { name: "A" }, condition: "new" },{ id: 7, type: { name: "A" }, condition: "new" },{ id: 8, type: { name: "B" }, condition: "broken" },{ id: 9, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "broken" }];
 
let op = data.reduce( (op,inp) => {
  if( op[inp.type] ){
    op[inp].chunks.push(inp)
  } else {
    op[inp] = {
      by: {...inp.type},
      chunks: [inp]
    }
  }
  return op
},{})

console.log(Object.values(op))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash as you mentioned before we could do:

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, type: { name: "A" }, condition: "new" },
  { id: 2, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "broken" },
  { id: 3, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "brand new" },
  { id: 4, type: { name: "B" }, condition: "broken" },
  { id: 5, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "brand new" },
  { id: 6, type: { name: "A" }, condition: "new" },
  { id: 7, type: { name: "A" }, condition: "new" },
  { id: 8, type: { name: "B" }, condition: "broken" },
  { id: 9, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "broken" }
];
const groups = _.groupBy(data, (val) => val.type.name)
const formattedGroupd = Object.keys(groups).map(groupKey => {
  return {
    by: {type: { name: groupKey }},
    chunks: groups[groupKey]
  }
});
console.log(formattedGroupd)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the way you assing the value to `by` in map. Assign like

```
 return {
      chunks: item,
      by: { type: item[0].type} 
    };
```

```js
const data = [
      { id: 1, type: { name: "A" }, condition: "new" },
      { id: 2, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "broken" },
      { id: 3, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "brand new" },
      { id: 4, type: { name: "B" }, condition: "broken" },
      { id: 5, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "brand new" },
      { id: 6, type: { name: "A" }, condition: "new" },
      { id: 7, type: { name: "A" }, condition: "new" },
      { id: 8, type: { name: "B" }, condition: "broken" },
      { id: 9, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "broken" }
    ];
    
    console.log(_.chain(data)
      .groupBy("type.name")
      .map((item, i) => {
        return {
          by: { type: item[0].type},
          chunks: item
        };
      })
      .value())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [
    { id: 1, type: { name: "A" }, condition: "new" },
    { id: 2, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "broken" },
    { id: 3, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "brand new" },
    { id: 4, type: { name: "B" }, condition: "broken" },
    { id: 5, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "brand new" },
    { id: 6, type: { name: "A" }, condition: "new" },
    { id: 7, type: { name: "A" }, condition: "new" },
    { id: 8, type: { name: "B" }, condition: "broken" },
    { id: 9, type: { name: "C" }, condition: "broken" }
];

const data2 = {};

data.forEach(test => {

    if (data2[test.type.name]) {
        data2[test.type.name].chunks.push({
            test
        });
    } else {
        data2[test.type.name] = {
            by: {
                type: test.type
            },
            chunks: [
                test
            ]
        };
    }
});

console.log(Object.values(data2));
```